# I want to open acra project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, acra

I try to import  acra http://code.google.com/p/acra/source/checkout to eclipse but the eclipse assume that it is standard java project so eclipse show me errors in imports

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
```

I mean any import related to Android causes errors, What is the ideal method to open acra source code in IDE ?

Comment: It might be helpful to try importing the latest version from https://github.com/ACRA/acra

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between Java projects and Android projects in Eclipse. The project should be an Android project in order to resolve the Android imports properly.
First make sure you have:

1. [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) installed on your computer.
2. [Android plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) installed in Eclipse.

Then in Eclipse go to menu `File > Import`, select `Android` and then `Existing Android code into workspace`

Alternatively you can try the dirty way and change your existing `.project` file to something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
<name>ACRA</name>
<comment></comment>
<projects>
</projects>
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: I marked the ACRA project as library project in eclipse. But still its classes are not importing in my another project.